# Remove entries if empty object or array in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following input JSON:

```
{
    "Accounts": [
        {
            "Reference": {
                "Key": "1111",
                "System": "Oracle"
            },
            "ContactMethods": {
                "Phone": [{...}, {...}, ...],
                "Email": [{...}, {...}, ...],
                "Address": [], // remove this
                "Website": [] // remove this
            },
            "Registration" : {...}
        },
        {
            "Reference": {
                "Key": "2222",
                "System": "DB2"
            },
            "ContactMethods": {
                "Phone": [{...}, {...}, ...],
                "Email": [], // remove this
                "Address": [], // remove this
                "Website": [{...}, {...}, ...]
            },
            "Registration" : {} // or null, remove this
        },
    ]
}
```

How do I remove the entries that are either empty object, empty array or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jolt does not support "conditional" removals.